# Finding a vector that is not an eigenvector of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 
> 4 & 3 &2 \\
> 3 & 1 & 5\\
> 4 &5 &5 
> \end{pmatrix}$  find a non-zero vector which is not an eigenvector of $A$

So of course the full way is to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but I am looking for another way.

I have taught about:

1. check if $A$ is invertible, if not $\lambda=0$ is not an eigenvalue and but then I can take any non-zero vector, but it could still be corresponding to an eigenvalue of $A$.

2.Take any linear combination of the columns of $A$

But non seems to be 100% right

Comment: Take a dice.  Throw it three times to get a $3$-dimensional vector.  I bet it will be no eigenvector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the $k^{th}$ column of an $n \times n$ matrix is the image of the $k^{th}$ standard basis vector; you can check that $\langle 1, 0, 0 \rangle$ gets sent to $\langle 4, 3, 4 \rangle$ under this transformation.

Comment: Thanks just had to take better  look at $Ax=\lambda x$